# Am I allowed to travel to Russia without a visa?

Tags: visas, dual-nationality, russia

I have dual German/Brazilian citizenship. Brazilian citizens are allowed to travel to Russia without visas, Germans are not. If, at the border, I presented both my passports without a visa, would I be refused entry to the country? Is it forbidden or immoral to present only one of my two passports?

Comment: Presenting only one passport is the normal state of affairs for dual citizens as far as I am aware.  Do you make a habit of presenting them both?  Do border officials typically look at both?  The few times I have indicated that I have two passports, the officer has ignored one of them.

Comment: I have presented both my passports once entering the UK from an international flight (from outside the EU). The border agent seemed puzzled for a few seconds, asked me some typical border control questions and let me through.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a rule, on entering a country you need to produce a valid travel document. There's no requirement to present more than one travel document, or every travel document you possess. You present your Brazilian passport at a border control, and that is probably all.

Same as you don't need a long-term Shengen visa in your Brazilian passport to live in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to only show one passport to Russian immigration authorities. If you have several passports, it could raise suspicion that you have fake travel documents. I would avoid any confusion for them, especially if you don't speak any Russian.

I would only reveal what is required of you, the Brazilian passport. If you don't need your German passport, leave it at home, as you wont want to lose it in Russia.

Also, your statement...

> "Brazilian citizens are allowed to travel to Russia without visas,
>   Germans are not."

is only partially *true*. According to [the Saint Petersburg travel info website](http://www.saint-petersburg.com/russian-visa/visa-free-travel/):

> "Brazil (for visits of up to 90 days in any 180-day period) - for
>   tourists, private visits or transit purposes only. In all other cases,
>   a visa is required. "

If your purpose is tourism, you are fine. If you plan to work or study, you will still need the proper visa, regardless of your citizenship. You didn't really specify your purpose of travel.

Comment: It is interesting that the visa exemption does not apply to business visitors; the similar visa exemptions I'm aware of in other countries do include business visitors.  Or does "private visits" include business visits?

Comment: @phoog the "visa free" regime in Russia is only for travel or personal visits. For business you should obtain a business visa.